# Using common model for view

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-events, backbone-model

We have written a base Backbone view class which abstracts the common methods and properties. All our view class in a module extends this base class. Also this classes use same model.

The model contains a collection. I am listening to change event of collection. Whenever there change in collection i want to listen for change event to the corresponding view. Instead this event is getting triggered for all the model instances created.

Please share your inputs to resolve this issue.

Comment: please include the relevant code

Answer (score 0):

in your base view, you can listen to model change events like this

```
intialize: function(options){
    ....... init code
    this.model.on('change',this.modelChanged, this);
}
```

then in the modelChanged handler you can trigger a custom event on the view

```
modelChanged: function(){
    this.trigger('modelChanged', [your args]);
}
```

then you can listen to the custom view event with 'on' function like we did with the model